# splitting a string into a multiple list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large text document that I am reading in and attempting to split into a multiple list. I'm having a hard time with the logic behind actually splitting up the string.

example of the text:

```
Youngstown, OH[4110,8065]115436
Yankton, SD[4288,9739]12011
966
Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826
1513 2410
```

This data contains 4 pieces of information in this format:

```
City[coordinates]Population Distances_to_previous
```

My aim is to split this data up into a List:

```
Data = [[City] , [Coordinates] , [Population] , [Distances]]
```

As far as I know I need to use .split statements but I've gotten lost trying to implement them.

I'd be very grateful for some ideas to get started!

Comment: In the first line of the data sample, it doesn't appear to show a value for "distances to previous". Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct, the idea is that the list starts and for each location, it includes the distance from the previous location. So the first one has 0 distances, 2nd city has distance from 1st, 3rd has distance from 2nd and 1st, and so on.

Comment: Is regex not feasible for some reason?

Comment: So it's `City[coordinates]Population\ndistances` is that right?

Comment: yes! with a space between Population and the distances.

Comment: Putting each part of a line into a list of 1 items, as you indicated, makes no sense and looks like an incredible waste of space.  I believe a list of strings, as in Beth Crane's answer, is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in stages.

- Your first split is at the '[' of the coordinates.
- Your second split is at the ']' of the coordinates.
- Third split is end of line.
- The next line (if it starts with a number) is your distances.

I'd start with something like:

```
numCities = 0
Data = []

i = 0
while i < len(lines):
    split = lines[i].partition('[')
    if (split[1]): # We found something
        city = split[0]
        split = split[2].partition(']')
        if (split[1]):
            coords = split[0] #If you want this as a list then rsplit it
            population = split[2]

    distances = []
    if i > 0:
        i += 1
        distances = lines[i].rsplit(' ')

    Data.append([city, coords, population, distances])
    numCities += 1
    i += 1

for data in Data:
    print (data)
```

This will print

```
['Youngstown, OH', '4110,8065', '115436', []]
['Yankton, SD', '4288,9739', '12011', ['966']]
['Yakima, WA', '4660,12051', '49826', ['1513', '2410']]
```

Comment: The difference between split and partition is that split takes the last instance of the separator, and partition takes the first

Comment: Having said all this, I'd probably recommend a dictionary referenced in by city, rather than just appending all your entries to a list.

Comment: Thanks! do you not have to explicitly define city, coords, population, and distances lists?

Comment: Python doesn't require you to explicitly declare variables, no. I declared distances just in case i was 0.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be with a regex.

```
lines = """Youngstown, OH[4110,8065]115436
Yankton, SD[4288,9739]12011
966
Yakima, WA[4660,12051]49826
1513 2410"""

import re

pat = re.compile(r"""
    (?P<City>.+?)                  # all characters up to the first [
    \[(?P<Coordinates>\d+,\d+)\]   # grabs [(digits,here)]
    (?P<Population>\d+)            # population digits here
    \s                             # a space or a newline?
    (?P<Distances>[\d ]+)?         # Everything else is distances""", re.M | re.X)

groups = pat.finditer(lines)
results = [[[g.group("City")],
            [g.group("Coordinates")],
            [g.group("Population")],
            g.group("Distances").split() if 
                    g.group("Distances") else [None]]
            for g in groups]
```

DEMO:

```
In[50]: results
Out[50]: 
[[['Youngstown, OH'], ['4110,8065'], ['115436'], [None]],
 [['Yankton, SD'], ['4288,9739'], ['12011'], ['966']],
 [['Yakima, WA'], ['4660,12051'], ['49826'], ['1513', '2410']]]
```

Though if I may, it's probably BEST to do this as a list of dictionaries.

```
groups = pat.finditer(lines)
results = [{key: g.group(key)} for g in groups for key in
                  ["City", "Coordinates", "Population", "Distances"]]
# then modify later
for d in results:
    try:
        d['Distances'] = d['Distances'].split()
    except AttributeError:
        # distances is None -- that's okay
        pass
```

Comment: Holy crap this is beyond my knowledge! how is this even splitting everything up? I've never seen a regex before

Comment: The `(?P<fieldname>...)` blocks are defining what goes in each field. They're commented so they should be easy enough to track. Basically grab everything up to the first `[` which is your city, then two sets of multiple digits separated by a comma as coordinates, then matches (but doesn't capture) a `]`. After that, any number of digits is your population until the first whitespace (which is a newline in your example but a space in your format, so I include the `re.M` flag which makes `\s` match a newline too), then any about of digit or space characters as distances.

Comment: Then it pulls `Match` objects out of the string by using `re.finditer`. We iterate through the group of `Match`es with a list comp to build your final list.

Comment: I deliberately avoided the regex because it seemed overly complex for the question, but you've explained it nicely.

Comment: @BethCrane I like regexes because although they're complicated to construct, they're fairly simple to look at and explain. In other words -- the guy who maintains my old code in five years will understand what the regex says, but will probably have to piece together the string splitting.